# Expo Print poor print quality

Tags: html, printing, expo

I am using the module Print from Expo. When I print the provided HTML to a printer, the content is extremely distorted. I believe it is due to Print having a default width of 612 and height of 792, which is a height of US Letter paper format with 72 PPI. Another reason I believe the print is blurry is because I am printing using HTML. Also, the print preview does not show the blurriness shown in the actual printed examples. I am printing to a label printer, so the HTML printed is extremely distorted because of how small the content is and how low the PPI is. To achieve a higher PPI, I changed the width and height of the Print:

```
await Print.printAsync({ html: printerHTML, width: 5000, height: 6471});
```

This did not work and did not seem to make a difference in the quality of the print. I tried setting height and width to 90,000 for 300 PPI, but an error is thrown when increasing height and width by that much.

When I attempt to print the same content to the same printer from Microsoft Word, the print is crystal clear and readable, so the printer is not the issue.

[Blurry print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEUCZ.jpg) /
[Clear print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyckC.jpg)

How do I print clear, non-blurry HTML using Expo Print?

Here is an example of the HTML that is being printed:

```
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
                <div style="display:inline; width:100%; padding: 0; text-align:left;">
                    <h1 style="font-size:9; font-family:arial">Quick Plate: ${quickPlateValue ? quickPlateValue.name : '-'}</h1>
                    <p style="font-size:9; font-family:verdana">Plate ID: ${qrData.id}</p>
                    <p style="font-size:9; font-family:courier">Dilution: ${plate.dilution ? plate.dilution : '-'}</p>
                </div>
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                    <img id='barcode' 
                        src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=savedPlate:${qrData.id}&amp;size=150x150" 
                        width="30"
                        height="30" 
                        style="text-align:center;"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Same issue here. Trying to print some QR Codes and it's helping to print larger but ideally I'd prefer them to be smaller with higher PPI so they're crisper and scan more quickly.